# PHP создать ассоциативный массив на основе слияния двух массивов

Tags: php, массивы, слияние

Есть два массива. Необходимо для каждого элемента первого массива найти соответствующие значения во втором массиве и создать третий ассоциативный.

Первый `$first = [ ['aaa', 74], ['bbb', 74], ['ccc', 55] ];`

Второй `$second = [ [74,'Petrov'], [55,'Ivanov'], [77,'Sidorov'] ];`

Результат `$result=['aaa'=>'Petrov', 'bbb'=>'Petrov', 'ccc'=>'Ivanov'];`

Заранее спасибо за отклик.

Comment: можете начать с `print_r(array_column($second, 1, 0));`

Comment: Здравствуйте, на SOru не приветсвуется задавать вопросы без своего решения. Вы должны привести задание, свой код, конкретную проблему (типа :"я не понимаю, почему на 14 строке происходит так или иначе" или "я нашел такое решение, с помощью такой функции, но она работает так, когда я ожидал другого и в документации написано вот что"). Обозначив свою проблему конкретно,прикрепив код и свои попытки справиться с проблемой вы сможете найти отклик!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: заводите третий пустой. Второй мапите в id => name. Идете по первому, берете значение, соответствие из второго и впихиваете в у третий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант реализации с циклами:

```
$first = [ ['aaa', 74], ['bbb', 74], ['ccc', 55] ];    
$second = [ [74,'Petrov'], [55,'Ivanov'], [77,'Sidorov'] ];
//$result=['aaa'=>'Petrov', 'bbb'=>'Petrov', 'ccc'=>'Ivanov'];
$list = [];
foreach($first as $item)
{
    foreach($second as $itemS)
    {
        if( $item[1] === $itemS[0] )
            $list[$item[0]]=$itemS[1];
    }
}

var_dump($list);
```